# Application.OnTime did not work

Tags: excel, vba, email

I try to send these worksheet automatically to emails with their corresponding recipients. Basically the coding will read the "Email" sheet which contain all the email address, cc and bcc. Then, the code will send desired sheet to the email listed in the "Email" sheet. the only thing I need right now is to make it automated. However the code Application.OnTime did not work for the whole coding. I dont know why.please help me guys.

```
Sub ExportEmail()

    Dim objfile As FileSystemObject
    Dim xNewFolder
    Dim xDir As String, xMonth As String, xFile As String, xPath As String
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim NameX As Name, xStp As Long
    Dim xDate As Date, AWBookPath As String
    Dim currentWB As Workbook, newWB As Workbook
    Dim strEmailTo As String, strEmailCC As String, strEmailBCC As String, strDistroList As String

    AWBookPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Creating Email and Attachment for " & Format(Date, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")

    Set currentWB = ActiveWorkbook

    xDate = Date

    '******************************Grabbing New WorkBook and Formatting*************

    Sheets(Array("Interval Data", "rawData")).Copy

    Set newWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("rawData").Visible = True
   ' Sheets("Cover").Select


    '******************************Creating Pathways*********************************

    xDir = AWBookPath
    xMonth = Format(xDate, "mm mmmm yy") & "\"

    xFile = "This is the automated report " & Format(xDate, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".xlsx"

    xPath = xDir & xMonth & xFile

    '******************************Saving File in Pathway*********************************

    Set objfile = New FileSystemObject

    If objfile.FolderExists(xDir & xMonth) Then
        If objfile.FileExists(xPath) Then
            objfile.DeleteFile (xPath)
            newWB.SaveAs Filename:=xPath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
            , CreateBackup:=False

            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Else
            newWB.SaveAs Filename:=xPath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
            , CreateBackup:=False
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
    Else
        xNewFolder = xDir & xMonth
        MkDir xNewFolder
        newWB.SaveAs Filename:=xPath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
            , CreateBackup:=False
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If

    '******************************Preparing Distribution List *********************************

    currentWB.Activate
    Sheets("Email").Visible = True
    Sheets("Email").Select

    strEmailTo = ""
    strEmailCC = ""
    strEmailBCC = ""

    xStp = 1

    Do Until xStp = 4

        Cells(2, xStp).Select

        Do Until ActiveCell = ""

            strDistroList = ActiveCell.Value

            If xStp = 1 Then strEmailTo = strEmailTo & strDistroList & "; "
            If xStp = 2 Then strEmailCC = strEmailCC & strDistroList & "; "
            If xStp = 3 Then strEmailBCC = strEmailBCC & strDistroList & "; "

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Loop

        xStp = xStp + 1

    Loop

    Range("A1").Select

    '******************************Preparing Email*********************************


    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
       Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
       Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
       olNs.Logon
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    olMail.To = strEmailTo
    olMail.CC = strEmailCC
    olMail.BCC = strEmailBCC


        olMail.Subject = Mid(xFile, 1, Len(xFile) - 4)
        olMail.Body = vbCrLf & "Hello Everyone," _
                            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please find attached the " & Mid(xFile, 1, Len(xFile) - 4) & "." _
                            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Regards," _
                            & vbCrLf & "--------"


    olMail.Attachments.Add xPath
    'olMail.Display

    olMail.Send

    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another Sub

to run this at Time 14:47

```
Sub test()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:47:00"), "ExportEmail"
End Sub
```

to run this 15 mins from now

```
Sub test()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "ExportEmail"
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you Danny Tan. I've tried that already but all I got is run time error. it says outlook does not recognize one or more names. any other suggestion?

Comment: ok, the error message sounds like you have a recipient name in your auto email that is not proper email nor names in your address book.

Comment: u're are such genius and lifesaver! problem solved. Thank you very much

Comment: one more thing though, will this macro work even when I didn't open it? will it send the email automatically?

Comment: Re your question, you need to run test() to trigger the OnTime code....
You can set this in VBScript if you do not want to open the sheet to trigger to it.

Comment: how exactly can I do that? sorry I'm new with vba

Comment: this is another question, suggest you start a new topic.. :)